# Android: get width of Layout programatically having fill_parent in its xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have the a `LinearLayout` with width set in xml as `fill_parent` , now i need its width at runtime programatically. So i did this:

```
    LinearLayout layoutGet=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.GameField1);
    LayoutParams layParamsGet= layoutGet.getLayoutParams();
    int width=layParamsGet.width;
```

But `width` value on debugging was found to be `-1`, anybody with idea why can't i get the exact width at runtime for LinearLayout with fill_parent set in layout xml.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I got a simple approach working.

```
myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
myLayout.post(new Runnable() 
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i("TEST", "Layout width : "+ myLayout.getWidth());

        }
    });
```

Jens Vossnack's approach mentioned below works fine. However, I found that the onGlobalLayout() method of GlobalLayoutListener is called repeatedly, which may not be appropriate in certain cases.

Comment: This was the answer i was searching for, i need to measure the View and use while the View is not yet layed-out, it always returned 0 until i found your answer, thanks

Comment: Why does it work well within a thread but outside the returns 0?

Comment: @e-info128 I think it's because hasn't drawn yet somehow.

Comment: For people wondering why it returns 0 at certain times, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)!

Answer (score 5):

You can try to listen to the globalLayout event, and get the width in there. You probably get the -1 because you are trying to get the width before the views are layed-out.

```
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       //Do it here
       LinearLayout layoutGet=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.GameField1);
       LayoutParams layParamsGet= layoutGet.getLayoutParams();
       int width=layParamsGet.width;
       removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutGet, this); // Assuming layoutGet is the View which you got the ViewTreeObserver from
    }
});

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener); 
    else v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}
```

(vto is the view you want to get the width of)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the value for `FILL_PARENT` (you should be using `MATCH_PARENT` since `FILL_PARENT` is now deprecated) you will notice the value for it is -1. `LayoutParams` are simply attributes for how your view should look. Once the view is inflated and looks the way the params specify, the view does not go back and change those Params to reflect the actual values of the view (width/height/etc).

If you wanted to get the actual width of your view you would have to call `getWidth()` on your view once the layout has been inflated and displayed. Calling `getWidth()` before your layout has been displayed will result in 0.

```
LinearLayout layoutGet=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.GameField1);
int width = layoutGet.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` (deprecated).

When you do `int width=layParamsGet.width;`, you take the right result which is `-1` corresponding at `fill_parent`.
If you wan't to get the real width, you need to wait `onMesure()` call and use

```
LinearLayout layoutGet=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.GameField1);
int width = layoutGet. getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: Which onMeasure() call are you talking about?

Answer (score -1):

`layoutGet.getWidth()` should work out