# Android Layout match_width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layoutparams

Is there anyway in `Android` to set the height of the `LinearLayout` to match it's width?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="MATCH_WIDTH_OF_THIS_LinearLayout"
```

I have the `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`'s width, and I want this `LinearLayout` to match it's own width for it's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, by using

```
android:adjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: Can't see this parameter in [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

set width in java code before the content has been layout,such as onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `myLayout.getWidth()` to get the width of the LinearLayout and set its height to that value. You'll need to do that in onCreate.

[Android: get width of Layout programatically having fill_parent in its xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081001/android-get-width-of-layout-programatically-having-fill-parent-in-its-xml)

[Android: How to Programmatically set the size of a Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798867/android-how-to-programmatically-set-the-size-of-a-layout)